# In C#, multiple diffrent classes in List

Tags: c#

I want to have a "connectionList" where every element a diffrent connection type (TCP,R232) is stored. I made an abstract interface to "Connect" and "Disconnect" but because "Config" needs diffrent parameters in each class, its not possible to implement it into the interface (or is it?).

I made a little visualitation:
[image: Problem visualitation]

One of my solutions would be to cast before the call like ((TCP)connectionList[0]).Config() but that means that i have to try every possible class type (TCP, RS232, ...) if i want for example to config the "Connection 3".

Im sure there are better solutions then this one.

Code example:

```
List<IConnection> connectionList = new List<IConnection>();

connectionList.Add(new TCP());
connectionList.Add(new RS232());

connectionList[0].Connect();
connectionList[1].Connect(); // Works

connectionList[0].Config(); //Does not work because not in Interface


public abstract class IConnection
{
    public abstract void Connect();
}

public class RS232 : IConnection
{
    private int _baudRate;
    
    public void Config(int baudRate)    //Diffrent parameters then in TCP
    {
        _baudRate = baudRate;
    }
    
    public override void Connect()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RS232 connect()");
    }
}

public class TCP : IConnection
{
    private int _ipAdress;
    
    public void Config(int ipAdress)    //Diffrent parameters then in RS232
    {
        _ipAdress = ipAdress;
    }
    public override void Connect()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TCP Connect()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `fluent interface pattern` for config.

Comment: What are you trying to achive by passing a list of unconfigured IConnections?
It seems to me If they are not configured they don´t really seem to contain any usefull information, so I´d either configure them before adding them to the list or create them as needed?

Comment: Yes you configure it before adding it but what if you want to re configure the connection??? @noel

Comment: In that case I don´t think there is a way around identifying the concrete type of the connection. Even if you wrap the parameters in some IConfiguration interface, you would still need to figure out which implementation you should use.

If you´re trying to dynamically render some UI for the config, you could provide each IConnection with an IConfiguration property and render it´s public properties through reflection, or use key value pairs (something like a Dictionary<string, string>)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some interfaces and maybe an abstract base-connection:

```
public interface ICanConnect
{
    public void Connect();
    public void Disconnect();
}

public interface IHaveConfig
{
    public IConnectionConfig GetConfig();
}

public interface IConnectionConfig
{
}

public interface ITcpConfiguration: IConnectionConfig
{
    public string IpAdress { get; set; }
}
// TODO add class

public interface IRS232Configuration : IConnectionConfig
{
    public int BaudRate { get; set; }
}
// TODO add class
```

The configuration should be done before you use the connections:

```
public abstract class BaseConnection : ICanConnect, IHaveConfig
{
    private IConnectionConfig _config;

    public BaseConnection(IConnectionConfig config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public IConnectionConfig GetConfig() => _config;

    public abstract void Connect();
    public abstract void Disconnect();
}
```

So you can add implementations for the TCP- and RS232-connections:

```
public class TcpConnection: BaseConnection
{
    public TcpConnection(ITcpConfiguration tcpConfig) : base(tcpConfig) { }

    public override void Connect()
    {
        ITcpConfiguration config = (ITcpConfiguration) base.GetConfig();
        // here you have the IP-Adress
    }

    public override void Disconnect()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class IRS232Connection : BaseConnection
{
    public IRS232Connection(IRS232Configuration rs232Config) : base(rs232Config) { }

    public override void Connect()
    {
         IRS232Configuration config = (IRS232Configuration) base.GetConfig();
        // here you have the Baud-Rate
    }

    public override void Disconnect()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With a `List<BaseConnection>` you can use the connect/disconnect methods(polymorphism):

```
// initialization
List<BaseConnection> connections = new List<BaseConnection>()
{
    new TcpConnection(new TcpConfiguration("192.158.1.38")),
    new RS232Connection(new RS232Configuration(2400)),
};

// use them
foreach(BaseConnection con in connections)
{
    con.Connect();
    con.Disconnect();
}
```

If you want to change the configuration later, for example the IP-Adress of the TcpConnections:

```
foreach (TcpConnection con in connections.OfType<TcpConnection>())
{
    ITcpConfiguration config = con.GetConfig() as ITcpConfiguration;
    config.IpAdress = "192.158.1.39";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i think this will only work if Configure() has again no/same  parameters.
I edited the post as you wanted before, maybe the problem is now clearer?

Comment: @Vladzzz: i have edited my answer. The configuration should be passed via constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your time but my main problem is changing the configuration during run time. Is that possible?

Comment: @Vladzzz: how do you know what must be configured and why you must replace the configuration after the connection is initialized? If you have multiple connection types in the same collection, then you have to find the correct one, that you want to modify. You can use `connections.OfType<TcpConnection>()` if you want to change the IP-Adress

Comment: I will have an UI where users can configure a connection but what if the configured IPAddress, Baud etc. is wrong or changed? They want to re configure it.

Comment: @Vladzzz: Edited my answer below, also changed the `IpAdress` to be get/set instead of get.

Comment: Okay, i get it. Thank you for the code given above!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dependency Injection you could configure each connection in your startup, or from a factory, if the configuration is dynamic.

```
    interface IConnection
    {
        void Connect();
        void Disconnect();
    }

    class RS232Conifguration
    {
        public int BaudRate { get; set; }
    }

    class RS232 : IConnection
    {
        private readonly RS232Conifguration _conifguration;

        public RS232(RS232Conifguration conifguration)
        {
            _conifguration = conifguration;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class TCPConfiguration
    {
        public int IpAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class TCP :IConnection
    {
        private readonly TCPConfiguration _configuration;

        public TCP(TCPConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton(new TCPConfiguration() { IpAddress = 423 });
    services.AddScoped<IConnection, TCP>();
            
    services.AddSingleton(new RS232Conifguration() { BaudRate = 4 });
    services.AddScoped<IConnection, RS232>();

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var connections = provider.GetServices<IConnection>();
```